# Cursor jumping to end of input field in jQuery Mask

Tags: jquery, input-mask

I use following code to input only alphabets and space character.

```
jQuery('.alpha-field').mask('Z',{translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[a-zA-Z ]/, recursive: true}}});
```

Now i face an issue with the masking plugin, that cursor moves to the end of string when i try to edit this.

I used regex initially to restrict alpha characters. But it did not work properly on mobile devices. This is the reason that i used the perfect solution of [jQuery Masking Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it like this:

```js
$(".alpha-field").on("keyup", function(event){
  const isNumber = isFinite(event.key);
  if(isNumber)
  this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
 })
```